# Flash Builder 4 and Debugging

Tags: eclipse, ant, flex4, flex3, flash-builder

I just wanted to ask a simple question. I am trying to work out the pros and cons of setting up Flash Builder 4, for Flex development, as an ant-build vs compiling via the IDE. I particularly want to ensure i can do the following:
  - Debug and Trace via IDE
  - Unit Testing via IDE

Is this possible through command-line building such as with ant? Are there any cons?
Thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unit testing I wouldn't know, but I think you can debug. Create a launch configuration that points to the swf created by the ant script, and use that to start debugging.